# Get RETURN value from ASMX web service

Tags: c#

Is it possible to get a return value from asmx web service, i have this code:

```
[WebMethod(CacheDuration = 0)]
public System.Xml.XmlDocument Load_DOK(System.Xml.XmlDocument XmlDoc)   
  {
  }
```

The INPUT parameter is XML DOCUMENT, and return message has to be a formatted  SOAP message, like this:

```
 soapEnvelop.LoadXml(@"<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema""><soap:Body><Response_status>0</Response_status><Description>SUCCESS</Description></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>");
return soapEnvelop;
```

This is a call with parameter passing to web service:

```
System.Xml.XmlDocument ReceivingXmlDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
 TestService.TestService ws_dok = new TEST.TestService.TestService();

 ws_dok.Load_DOK(SendingXmlDoc);
```

So is it possible to extract that return?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should be as simple as this:

```
XmlDocument receivingXmlDoc = ws_dok.Load_DOK(sendingXmlDoc);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes this way because you have already declare the `webmethod Load_DOK to return as XmlDocument`

```
XmlDocument doc=  ws_dok.Load_DOK(SendingXmlDoc);
```

Comment: I got an error: Error 11 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Xml.XmlNode' to 'System.Xml.XmlDocument'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Please can you show me the code that throws this error and also the full code of Load_DOK